# How to add the white lines in the letters in Photoshop?

Tags: typography, text, lettering

[image]

Please see the attached image, how to add the white lines in the letters in Photoshop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so it's not an exact solution, but it's definitely easier than drawing in the lines on a font that doesn't already have them.

Start with your text

[image: text]

Change the color of the text to white (or whatever your design's background color is) and then add an `Inner Stroke` of the color that you wish the font to be.

[image: stroke]

And there you have it

[image: stroked]

You can also achieve this same effect, using an `Inner Glow`, which will allow for more flexibility in the final result.

Use settings similar to what I have below:

[image: glow]

And they will give you this

[image: glowing]

Mess around with it, see what you can do, or find a font that already looks the way you want it to.  I prefer the `Inner Glow` method, because it opens up *way* more options (adjust your contour, choke, range, noise, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to keep that blank space transparent. To achieve that just change the Fill of your text layer to 0%

[image: Fill zero percent]

And this is the result.

[image]